# Get factors of a large number - typically 12 digit number... No output

Tags: c#, time-complexity, factorial

Folks i have a sample console application which has a method that calculates the factors of the given number and returns the same as list.

If the input number is less than 9 digits the program is working fine however if the number is a 12 digit number, the execution goes on forever and there is no output and no exceptions also.

I have attached the execution code...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var list = GetFactors(600851475143);
}

static List<long> GetFactors(long bigNum)
{
    var list = new List<long>();
    long counter = 1;
    try
    {
        while (counter <= bigNum / 2)
        {
            if (bigNum % counter == 0)
            {
                list.Add(counter);
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Add some "progress" printiouts. It probably simply takes that long with a brute force algorithm as yours.

Comment: Well, that's some big number you're trying to calculate. Have you tried debugging this with a smaller number?

Comment: Also, use `unsigned long` and check input against largest possible unsigned long (hint: this is tricky)

Comment: This `try...catch...throw` thing looks funny.

Comment: By "factors", what exactly do you mean? Do you mean any number that the original number is divisible by? Or do you mean the to factorise the number? Can you give some examples of what you expect of, say, 8, 16, 23, 100? For instance for 8, are the factors "2, 2, 2" or are the "factors" "1, 2, 4, 8" ?

Comment: 9 digits takes a fat 4 seconds, give or take.  When you use 12 then it will take a *thousand* times longer.  The simple mistake you are making is not having patience enough to wait for an hour+ for the result.

Answer (score 3):

...which is to be expected.
Most of cryptographic algorithms are based on how computationally expensive it is to compute (prime) factors of a given number.
The increment in the cost is not linear, so most likely, the jump between 9 and 12 digits is too big (with that unoptimized algorithm) that you won't be able to see the result anytime soon.

There are several documents about it on the net, just one among them many:
http://computer.howstuffworks.com/computing-power.htm